# Cannot initiate class from compiled TypeScript/NPM/Webpack module

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

Somehow I couldn't ask the question without having an error concerning the code not being marked up correctly, so I moved most of it to GitHub here: 
https://github.com/JoepBC/typescript-packages-example-error

The problem comes down to this: Using the package structure as on GitHub (using TypeScript, webpack and ts-loader), I have two packages, LibA and LibB, where LibB wants to load objects from the compiled LibA TS->JS code (.d.ts definition files for LibA are created fine).

The code for '~/A/src/index.ts' is as follows:

```
import {TestExport} from './test_export.ts';
export class Foo extends TestExport {
    constructor(text:string) {
        super(text);
        console.log("added by the extended class");
    }
}
let a = new Foo('bar');
```

The code for '~/A/src/test_export.ts' being:

```
export class TestExport {
    constructor(text:string) {
        console.log("TestExport constructor argument:"+text);
    }
}
```

The source for '~/B/src/index.ts' is:

```
import * as LibA from 'liba';
console.log('----');
let a = new LibA.Foo('arg1');
```

The generated javascript code for Lib A runs as expected. Lib B tries to import from A (as A imports from another file [although not compiled] within the same packages fine), and the javascript code from A can be run within B, but in B I cannot initiate a new object from a class from A.

The result when running B is:

```
~/B/dist $ node index.js 
TestExport constructor argument:bar
added by the extended class
----
webpack:///./src/index.ts?:5
var a = new LibA.Foo('arg1');
        ^
TypeError: LibA.Foo is not a constructor
    at eval (webpack:///./src/index.ts?:5:9
    at Object../src/index.ts (~/B/dist/index.js:108:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (~/B/dist/index.js:20:30)
    at ~/B/dist/index.js:84:18
    at Object. (~/B/dist/index.js:87:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
```

Different ways of requiring/importing A inside B don't seem to work either... How should this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like importing one Webpack bundle directly into another Webpack project doesn't work, but there are some options.  See [this thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2361).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Matt. The import of the generated javascript does seem to work and static code is executed fine. The calling of functions or the use of classes from A seems to be problematic. When the TypeScript compiler is called without the use of webpack and the resulting javascript source is executed the same problem occurs.

Comment: examples of the typescript and javascript code and output are updated at https://github.com/JoepBC/typescript-packages-example-error/blob/master/B/src/

Comment: When the .ts code for liba and libb is compiled to .js manually, without using npm or webpack, it works as expected: https://github.com/JoepBC/typescript-packages-example-error/tree/master/example_works_without_webpack . So somewhere in the process webpack is obstructing liba to be imported "normally" inside libb.

Comment: In essence, the problem is that a Webpack bundle is designed to resolve internal references among the included modules but doesn't export anything.  Static code will work, but you won't be able to access functions or classes.  You'll need to use a different approach; see the thread I linked above for alternatives.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done with the right config-parameters (but I can't find out which ones, it's such a an extensive incomprehensible mess to work through). I now chose to use the tsc compiler to compile the libraries (liba in the example) and webpack (with ts-loader and typescript) to compile the final typescript application to be used from the browser. It works, but it's a workaround. Thanks for thinking along with me.